# Transferring a stream of data seperated by carriage return to a list box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

while I've visited the site several times over the years this is my first question that prompted me to make an account.

Essentially I have an .exe that will download online videos, it's a command line program. I have succeeded in rerouting the stream from command prompt while keeping the cmd window from opening. However here is where my problem occurs: When I'm pulling a single video title from the site I can add that line of text to my list box no problem with my code. But when I point to a playlist, my current method of rerouting the data put's it all in a stream. so when I add it to the list box all of the video titles are in one line. Where as in my text box for testing purposes I can see each video listed on a new line (meaning it's keeping the formatting from how it would show up in cmd). Is there any GENERAL way to iterate through the redirected data and add my video titles accordingly ?  (see code below)

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    vidURL = txtURL.Text.ToString()
    options = "-e " + vidURL


    Dim info As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(youtubeDL, options)
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    info.CreateNoWindow = True
    info.UseShellExecute = False


    Dim process As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    process.StartInfo = info
    process.Start()

    If process.Id > 0 Then
        Label1.Text = "Process Started"

    End If

    vidTitle = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

    process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()


    lstAvailableVids.Items.Add(vidTitle.ToString())
    lstAvailableVids.Items.Add("test")

    txtVideoDescription.Text = vidTitle

    process.Close()


End Sub
```

As it is - I will only ever add one item to the list box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `vidTitle` contains all of the video titles on separate lines when you display it in a textbox, then you can parse that into a string array by whatever the delimiter is and loop over it adding each item to your listbox.

```
'Assumes the delimiter is vbCrLf
Dim vidTitles() As String = Split(vidTitle.ToString(), vbCrLf) 
For Each t In vidTitles
    lstAvailableVids.Items.Add(t)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks man I'll check this out later. I'm pretty sure it works, I just wasn't sure how I would iterate through the stream to seperate for the list box I appreciate it!